# In python code, how do you hide split sections in an epub so they do not display in an ereader's Nav toc?

Tags: python, html, split, epub

I'm writing a text to epub conversion program in python using markdown. I want to be able to use mark-up to split the chapters, headers like you can in Sigil. Everything that I've tried from scanning and copying the methods of other epubs(that do not show these split sections) has failed.

My coded mark-up splitter works, but the split sections always show in the ereader's Nav TOC on conversion with ADE and Kindle. I've also tried mangling the section id's in the spine and manifest and adding appropriate HTML titles to these split sections, which also didn't work.

So can anyone tell me how I can split an epub header or chapter section so that the split section name does not display (i.e. is hidden) in any ereader's Nav TOC?

Comment: I do not understand well your question. If you are writing the whatever-to-EPUB converter, then you can choose what entries you put in your NCX (if EPUB 2) or Navigation Document (if EPUB 3). In theory, reading applications would display only the "tree" contained in your NCX/NavDoc file. Please provide some input/expected output example code.

Comment: The way to have no display in the ereader NCX TOC is to remove all entries within the toc.ncx xml file within the epub. But you will have to have at least one blank entry in the toc.ncx Navpoint xml structure for it to pass IDPF epubcheck.